# How to use custom fonts on Vue native?

Tags: react-native, vue.js, fonts, font-face, vue-native

I'm trying to use a custom font on my vue native app, but dontt find how to do this. I've tried use @font-face.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0IjD.png)

i found something like Font.loadAsync from react native, but i don't know how to use this

Comment: One should never ever post code/error message as an image. It must be always text that  is easy to analyze /read

Answer (score 0):

I been using expo documentation, perhaps [this](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/) can leads you to a solution

Edit:
Well after installing the given font package, I imported expo-font in my app.vue file then I loaded inside the google font package and that's all

```js
//App.vue
import * as Font from "expo-font";

Font.loadAsync({
  VT323_Regular: require("./node_modules/@expo-google-fonts/vt323/VT323_400Regular.ttf"),
});

//export default { ...
```

```css
.myText {
  font-family: VT323_Regular;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <view class="container">
  
   <text class="myText">ABCDEF</text>
    
  </view>
</template>
```